# What does it mean when an answer's text is in a light color?

Tags: support, answers

Some of the answers' text are in light grey. What does this indicate?

Comment: It probably means they got heavily downvoted. Can you post screenshot?

Comment: Link to the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grayish color answers are shown once the answer reaches a score of -3 and less.

This may be reasoned as the answer is not suitable/correct.

Comment: What's the purpose.. so people don't notice it anymore?

Comment: @Tony_Henrich Maybe that, or the fact that the answer is not suitable/correct. For users not to notice an answer, it can be deleted too.

Comment: "The more negative votes it acquire, the lighter its shade gets." This isn't true.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: [Screenshot to contradict your comment.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KAVia.png)

Comment: @007 [Optical illusion](http://i.imgur.com/3fPJCC7.png) and/or minor browser font rendering issues caused by the bold text in the other answer. Browser dev tools confirm that both are `rgb( 136, 136, 136 )`.

Comment: @Juhana: Yep! It's illusion. `:P`